# Eslint style guide not detect in visual studio code

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

My package.json contains the following

```
"eslint-config-airbnb-base": "^12.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
```

and `eslintrc.json` in root folder

```
{
    "extends": ["airbnb-base"]
}
```

Also, I've installed eslint plugin in VisualStudio code, but the lint has not detected the errors in my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should install `eslint` in your project aswell if you haven't : `npm i -S eslint` .

Then create a `.eslint.js` in the root of your project and add the following:

`module.exports = { "extends": "airbnb-base" };`

Install the ESLint extension for VSCode, reload VSCode. 
If it still does't work, open the command palette, search for `ESLint: Disable ESLint`, then enable it again.

I created a [sample VSCode project on github](https://github.com/dubonzi/eslint-sample) with the basics you'll need. It worked fine on my machine, feel free to clone it.

Comment: Your link is not available anymore.